Python use delimited string to access element in nested dictionary
I'm trying load a yaml file and access elements from it by a / delimited string.
Sample yaml file:
foo:
  bar:
    baz: qux
  corge: waldo

I'm loading that file with:
import yaml
data = yaml.load(open(yamlfile), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

I can then access quz with
data['foo']['bar']['baz']

But is there a way to access it by a delimited string, something like this?
data.get_by_full_path('/foo/bar/baz')

Edit:
Thanks for the linked post that provides some ways to do it.  I may wind up using one of those.  Here is another solution I remembered from working with jsonpath previously.
from jsonpath_ng import parse
parse('foo.bar.baz').find(data)[0].value
# 'qux'


Hi. You can find answers in this question. Check out the first answer and replace "." with "/" as the delimiter.

dict objects do not suppor that, but it is pretty trivial to write code to do that
